# Typography standard for the space before the punctuation mark in equation

Tags: spacing, equations

Due to obvious stylistic and non-confusion reasons, some extra space is typically added at the end of the displayed equation, before the punctuation mark:

```
\begin{equation}
x=0.05\somespace,
\end{equation}
```

Same question for

```
\begin{equation}
x=0.05\somespace,\someextraspace y=1.23\somespace,
\end{equation}
```

I personally use `\somespace=\quad` and `\someextraspace=\qquad` which would seem ugly for most people but works fine for me and can be changed easily on the editing stage.

Are there any latex/typography standards covering these issues? Or just the personal taste?

Comment: There will be various traditions, schools and house styles available, English, French, Russian, ISO, etc. For example, the AMS style: http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf

Comment: `\qquad` is appropriate for what you've indicated as `\someextraspace`; at least, that is what the AMS editors would apply.  For space before punctuation, `\quad` is too much; this is generally a matter of personal preference, but a thin space `\,` is usually sufficient unless whatever precedes the punctuation appears too close, e.g., a fraction.  In any case, visual consistency is important.